# Best method to filter out an item from custom model

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, module, frontend, custom

I have a custom module using which we can add banner images in admin. I have implemented this module in the admin successfully. Now I want to display banner in the front end.

My custom table is given below

```
table name : banner
     fields: banner_name  |  store_ids  |  images  |   img_path  |  status
```

Store ids and Images are stored as `comma-seperated-values`. Now I want to select a banner item which corresponds to the current store view. Here is my code that I have tried to display banner module in the frontend.

```
<?php
    //get all active banner items as array
    $bannerItems = Mage::getModel('banner/banner') -> getCollection()
                -> addFieldToFilter('status',1) -> getItems(); //select only enabled items                  
    $curStoreId = Mage::app() -> getStore() -> getId(); //get current store id
    $banner = "";
    foreach($bannerItems as $item) 
    {    
         $data = $item -> getData();
         /*
             Store ids are saved as `comma separated values`. Hence making
             all store_ids as an array
         */
         $storearray = explode(",",$data['store_id']);
         foreach($storearray as $store)
         {                          
             if($store == $curStoreId) //check for matches, if yes load the item
             {               
                 $banner = $item;
                 break;               
             }

         }        
         if($banner != "") // ensure to store the first matched item to load
         {
             break;
         }

     }
     //output
     if( empty($banner) ) 
     {
         die("no banner exist for this store.Please add a banner !!!");
     }
     else
     {
         die( print_r( $banner->getId() ) );
     }
?>
```

This provide me banner model correspond for the current store view. However I feel that this code is lengthy. So I need to know how i can achieve this at its best. Please provide your suggestions. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not "tested" this but this should be helpful.

```
$currentStore = 5;

$bannerItems = Mage::getModel('banner/banner') -> getCollection()
            -> addFieldToFilter('status',1);
$bannerItems->getSelect()->where("FIND_IN_SET($currentStore, store_ids) > 0");
$bannerItems->getSelect()->orWhere("store_ids = 0");
$bannerItems->getSelect()->order("(FIND_IN_SET($currentStore, store_ids) > 0 ) * 10 DESC");
```

First find out the current store_id (1, used for example) using `FIND_IN_SET` and also look for store_ids =0, but sort the former result if exists in descending order so that you can get the required result at first row.

After that just use `$bannerItems->getFirstItem()`, everthing has been already done in the query.

Comment: thanks for the reply. my `store_ids` attribute will be look like this. `4,5,6` (an example).if current store_id is 5, then i need to return this banner item. but this code seem to be comparing storeids as assumin `store_ids` attribute posses only one value. `store_ids` is a string actually. However this is a new info for me. :). does this work in my case then??

Comment: Please see the edited code. I think that should work now in your case.

Comment: i have tried your code. i have tried lot. but appear to be not working

Comment: Can you see what Query was formed and could you run that query directly on DB server, see what query you will get after - `$bannerItems->printlogquery(true)`

Comment: output is like, when print your code:  `from] => Array
                (
                    [main_table] => Array
                        (
                            [joinType] => from
                            [schema] => 
                            [tableName] => banner
                            [joinCondition] => 
                        )

                )

            [where] => Array
                (
                    [0] => (status = '1')
                    [1] => AND (FIND_IN_SET(4, store_ids) > 0)
                    [2] => OR (store_ids = 0)
                )
`

Comment: i think sql code work perfectly then. but getFirstItem() returns nothing

Comment: Printlogquery should echo SQL Query! not a select Object, write the printlogquery after the last line in query and then see what SQL query is made - It should be something like this :`SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` WHERE (FIND_IN_SET(1, store_id) > 0) OR (store_id = 0) ORDER BY (FIND_IN_SET(1, store_id) > 0 ) * 10 DESC`

Comment: `SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `banner` AS `main_table` WHERE (status = '1') AND (FIND_IN_SET(4, store_ids) > 0) OR (store_ids = 0) ORDER BY (FIND_IN_SET(4, store_ids) > 0 ) * 10 DESC`   this is the output

Comment: wow. i have tried your code. Now it worked perfectly. thanks for this great solution.can we achieve this using addFieldToFilter() only? when will we prefer this method over getSelect() method?